# ¿Por qué me sale este error de compilación al descargar Angular?

Tags: angular, localhost, style, compilacion

Esta imagen muestra el sistema en el que trabajo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He descargado Angular para un proyecto nuevo, y al ejecutar el comando ng serve, me aparece el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aún así al hacer ctrl + click en localhost:4200 redirige a una pantalla en blanco con un mensaje ==>

cannot get /

Quiero manifestar además que he eliminado node_modules e instalado nuevamente con npm install, cambié en app.component.ts en styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'] a [app.component.scss'] y tampoco.
Quiero aclarar que mi sistema operativo es windows 7. No se a qué se debe no poder acceder al localhost para poder ver mi archivo y continuar con el proyecto.

Muchas gracias, por dedicar un poco de su tiempo para ayudar.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69191478/5525964

Comment: al crear un nuevo proyecto podes seleccionar scss o css Si seleccionas al inicio scss Comprobaste en tu proyecto la configuración de angular.json "styles".[ "src/styles.scss"] y que exista styles.scss y que en app.component.ts  styleUrls apunte a ./app.component.scss y que este ultimo archivo  si tenga la terminación .scss..Copiaste codigo dentro del proyecto inicial?

Comment: Creamos un proyecto totalmente nuevo, y no compila, aparece este error al ejecutar ng serve.

Comment: Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/#YoProgramo/PortafolioWebYeimer/src/app/app.component.css?ngResource' in 'C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\#YoProgramo\PortafolioWebYeimer'

Comment: Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\#YoProgramo\PortafolioWebYeimer\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?protocol=auto%3A&username=&password=&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=0&pathname=%2Fng-cli-ws&logging=info&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=false&live-reload=true' in 'C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\#YoProgramo\PortafolioWebYeimer'

Comment: Error: The loader "C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/#YoProgramo/PortafolioWebYeimer/src/app/app.component.css" didn't return a string.



** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


× Failed to compile.